# Unable to resolve class Error in included external gradle build file

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

What I'm trying to accomplish is to group some common tasks and functions under a common.gradle file and reuse those tasks and methods in different projects by simply calling in the main build.gradle:

```
apply from: 'common.gradle'
```

I have this following method in the common.gradle file:

```
def readPackageNameFromManifest() {
    def manifestParser = new com.android.builder.DefaultManifestParser()
    return manifestParser.getPackage(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile) 
}
```

But it keeps telling me :

```
> Could not compile script 'common.gradle'
 unable to resolve class com.android.builder.DefaultManifestParser 
   @ line 77, column 26.
         def manifestParser = new com.android.builder.DefaultManifestParser()
```

It's not causing any problem when I move the method under build.gradle.

I might be missing a point. I would appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must instruct gradle that your build script in common.gradle depends on android-gradle-plugin.

Add this to common.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to create a new task in an external script using a plug-in defined in the build.gradle plugins{...}. I found out that gradle uses separate class loaders for external scripts, and, even so plugins {} cannot be used anywhere other than the main file, this legacy-style solution worked for me. Thank you for that!